# Stoner-Wohlfarth model for ferromagnetism

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

I'm studing the Stoner-Wohlfarth model for ferromagnatism on the book Ibach-Luth Solid state physics. During the derivation of the Stoner criterion I found this passage (8.43) not so clear for me:

- why moving from summation to integral, they divide by $(2\pi)^3/V$ (I suppose this is the volume occupied by a single $k-$state)?
- why the integral becomes the density of state at Fermi Energy $ D(E_F) $ (more or less)?

[image]

Comment: Correct, the factor is the $k$ space volume. And the Fermi-Dirac distribution at $T = 0$ is a step function. It has its "cliff" at the Fermi level $E_F$, above which states are unoccupied, and where the distribution thus goes to zero. Since it's a step function, its derivative is zero everywhere except $\tilde E = E_F$, where it is infinite. The result is a Dirac delta centered at $E_F$. However, I am equally confused by the very last step; hopefully someone else can clarify.

Comment: For the last step, note that the integral in k space is over the k-surface defined by ${\tilde E} = E_F$, and the delta function is a "surface delta", see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Properties_in_n_dimensions and the links therein. Its integral gives the size of the surface in k space, which in turn gives the density of states at $E_F$.

Comment: @KyleArean-Raines : I understand the passage from the step function to the Dirac delta. What is not clear to me is why they divide by that volume? Because the integral os over k? So, why don't divide by the volume V of the sample?

Comment: @udrv: I have some gaps about these mathematical aspects. Why is it a "surface delta"? Or better, I guess: why this volume integral over the k-space can be seen as a surface integral? Because the delta function is different from zero only at that surface and so the space integral collaps to a surface integral? If this is the correct interpretation where disappears the factor $ (2\pi)^3 $?

Comment: It's a "surface delta" because the points for which ${\tilde E} = E_F$ are located on a surface in k space. The usual definition of the density of states is $$ g(E) = N^{-1} \sum_{{\bf k}, \sigma} {\delta\left( E - E_\sigma({\bf k})\right)}$$ where $\sigma$ labels spin, and in d dimensions the sum goes into an integral by the recipe $$\sum_{\bf k}{(\dots)} \rightarrow \int{d^d{\bf k} /\left[ (2\pi/L)^d\right]}$$

Comment: From this I can only surmise that the factor of $(2\pi)^{-3}$ is absorbed into _their_ definition of $D(E_F)$, which they promptly redefine afterwards into something that looks very much like the _usual_ density of states.